# как расположить элементы правильно как на макете?

Tags: css3

[image: как надо]
[image: как есть]

как расположить элементы правильно как на макете?

Comment: приложите ваш код к вопросу

Comment: а можно ли выровнять как-то только с помощью inline блоков? без флексов, без позиционирования, без табличной верстки.

Answer (score 1):

Такую реализацию можно сделать на флексах

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="col1">
  Контент
</div>
<div class="col2">
    <div class="col2-1">Контент</div>
    <div class="col2-1">Контент2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.col2 div{
  width:100px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbxKJJ

Что бы раскидать блоки по вертикали, смотрите свойства: align-items, align-content